# Reciprocal of a binomial random variable

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, random-variable

> A production line produces faulty items independently at random with
>   probability p.
>
> (a) Let X be the number of faulty items in a batch of 10. What is the
>   distribution of X, and what is P(X = k)?
>
> (b) Let Y be the number of items you have to check to find 2 faulty
>   ones. What is the distribution of Y, and what is P(Y = n)?
>
> (c) Give values of k and n for which P(X ≥ k) = P(Y ≤ n).

My answer:

**P(X) = 10CX . p^X . (1-p)^(10-X)**

a) P(X=k) = 10Ck . p^k . (1-p)^(10-k)

b) Yp = 2 -> Y = 2/p = 2/(X/10) = 20/X

I don't know how to proceed from here. I am tempted to find an inverse distribution function. But I don't think it is appropriate for discrete function and more than that I don't think the question is asking for a complex solution.

You can correct if my solution to part a is incorrect, ie if the variable X is not binomial distributed.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag and read its wiki

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I added the tag. I need to see some similar examples atleast. Not wiki page

Comment: @DomJo it means read the wiki of self-study tag

Comment: (b) makes little sense because $X$ and $Y$ are counts.  That suggests reconsidering what question (2) is asking.

Comment: @whuber I changed my steps in question b)

Comment: Have you perchance been learning about applications of the *negative binomial* distribution?

Comment: @whuber Actually Im a 25 year old tutor. I came across this question by a student which got me curious. I don't know which specific topic this is about. The steps I wrote is based on my initial intuition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b) Negative Binomial Distribution with parameters p and x = 2

$$ P(n) = {^{n-1}}C_{2-1}.p^{2}.(1-p)^{n-2} $$